# How %c and %s works in C language?

Tags: c, char, printf

Here afaik, `%s` will keep on printing until it gets the termination character i.e. `\0`.

How does `%c` knows about termination and end up printing only one character?

Comment: it always print 1 character, no magic required

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html (Guessing you want to ask about `printf`. In which case you really should read the docs, linked for your convenience.)

Comment: With a `%c` format, `printf` doesn't need to know about termination.

Comment: BTW, it's '\0' not '/0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%c` and `%s` are part of the `printf()` functions in the standard library, not part of the language itself.

That being said, `printf()` uses the character(s) following `%`, along with the [stdarg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html) functions, to determine what type of variable it will read from its arguments and what it will do with it. A highly simplified implementation of `printf()` might look like the following.

Note in particular that `%c` and `%s` do *not* deal with the same type of arguments! `%c` deals with a `char` (that is, a single character), whereas `%s` deals with a `char *` (that is, a pointer to an array of characters, hopefully null-terminated).

```
int printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);     // Initialize stdargs

    const char *p = fmt;   // Pointer into the format string
    while (*p != '\0') {
        char ch = *p++;    // Get the next character of the format string

        if (ch != '%') {   // Not a format character? Just print it
            putchar(ch);
            continue;
        }

        char fmt = *p++;   // Get the character following the %

        if (fmt == 'd') {
            int n = va_arg(ap, int);
            print_number(n);

        if (fmt == 'c') {
            char c = va_arg(ap, char);
            putchar(c);

        } else if (fmt == 's') {
            char *str = va_arg(ap, char *);
            print_string(str);

        } else {
            // Unrecognized format character
        }
    }

    va_end(ap);

    return n;
}
```

Comment: ---> `int c = va_arg(ap, int); putchar(c);`

Answer (score 3):

String formatting is not a feature of C or the language.  Is is a facility provided by the C runtime library.

"%c" doesn't need a terminator because it only processes one character.

"%s" continues to process characters until it encounters an ASCII NUL character which is expressed in C as '\000' (or '\0').  A forward slash in a string or character constant is a printable character without any special meaning.

Additionally, almost every C runtime library provides considerably more control over the `%s` length:

- `%.123s` processes up to 123 characters if a NUL is not encountered
- `%.*s` needs two matching parameters: the first is an integer which specifies the maximum field width and the second is the char pointer.  Example:  `printf ("x = %.*s\n", 15, ptr);`

Answer (score 2):

%c always prints a single character.

```
char x = 'a';
```

Here we have a single character a which needs to be printed.

```
char x[2] = "a";
```

In the above example we have 2 characters one is `'a'` and another is `'\0'`.

So while printing we need to use %s so that it encounters end of string thorough '\0' and prints the string.

Answer (score 2):

%c means character, range is 0x00 to 0xff (Unsigned) that is 1 byte, a memory location can hold 1 byte of data, %c will print data from one memory location only, so termination character is not required.

%s means stream of characters means it has to get data from stream of memory locations so it requires a termination character, Hence '\0' is required for %s.