# the 'getchar' function in c

Tags: c, char, scanf, newline, getchar

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 6;
    while (n--){
        int c = getchar();
        printf("%c",c);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

can anyone please explain the code above? like if I give an input something like this

```
99999
```

I get an output like this

```
99999
```

but I pressed 'Enter' after giving five nines, but how all the nines are read? I mean if I use scanf I have to press enter after each input, but I didn't do this there, I am assigning the return value of getchar to an int variable, it cannot store five ints together, so how does the getchar function reading all five-nines together at a time?

Comment: Because the 5 nines are all present in the input buffer, and are available for the program to read after you press <Enter>. The same is true for `scanf` too - a newline is not necessarily *required* after each item, only to terminate the sequence.

Comment: Simpler to use putchar as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How %c and %s works in C language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707429/how-c-and-s-works-in-c-language)

Comment: read the [documentation of `%c`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: and [getchar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar)

Answer (score 2):

This is not really related to the C language, but to the Operating System and the Input-Output subsystem.

By default, terminal output is line oriented, meaning that the low-level system (drivers and/or system routines) buffer what is typed on the keyboard and only provide data to the program when a line is completed (Carriage Return or Line Feed is given).

In Unix like systems (Linux, ...), you could set the terminal in raw mode with `stty raw` to make your C program able to process one character at a time as soon a it is typed. But beware it has nasty side effects like requiring <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> to enter a new line...

Answer (score 0):

If you will run this demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    size_t n = 6;
    
    while ( n-- )
    {
        int c = getchar();
        printf( "%c", c );
    }
    
    n = 6;
    
    while ( n-- )
    {
        char c;
        scanf( "%c", &c );
        printf( "%c", c );
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

and two times enter the sequence

```
99999
```

and after each you will press the Enter key you will get identical outputs for the both while loops

```
99999
99999
```

That is the both calls

```
int c = getchar();
```

and

```
scanf( "%c", &c );
```

will read sequentially digits 9 and after them they will read the new line character `'\n'`.

The notable difference between using `getchar` and `scanf` for reading characters is that you can skip reading white space characters using `scanf` by inserting a blank in the format string as for example

```
scanf( " %c", &c );
       ^^^^^
```

If you will make this change in the demonstrative program above and will enter the sequence

```
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
```

then the program output will be

```
9
9
9
999999
```